# Add Multiple Events between dates in Calendar - IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am working on calendar app where i need to add multiple events in iphone calendar[image].

I search many demo but none of meets my requirements.

I am attaching a screenshot for what kind it must looks and fill with events.

please help me if any of know how to do same in Iphone app.

Help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Why down votes?

If you can not answer or if you don't know then please at least do not down vote :(

Comment: https://github.com/witochandra/CalendarView Try this

Comment: Thanks @PayalManiyar for reply. Yes i used this and reviewing for more customization

Comment: is this query solved.?

Comment: Not yet :( 
I have review the CalenderView Demo of GitHub but its lil complicated with my custom modifications , i am playing with demo with my customisations

Comment: @Anita have you achieve exactly this if yes then please let me know how.

Comment: @Anita Even i am looking for the same solution. If you found something, please post it here, so it could be helpful for others too

Answer (score 2):

Try This - you just need to set End Date

```
func addEvent() {
    let store = EKEventStore()
    store.requestAccess(to: .event) {(granted, error) in
        if !granted { return }
        let event = EKEvent(eventStore: store)
        event.title = "Event Title"
        event.startDate = Date() //today
        /// Add as much long event you want
        /// I think this is what you need
        event.endDate = event.startDate.addingTimeInterval(60*60)//1 hour long meeting
        event.calendar = store.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
        do {
            try store.save(event, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
            self.savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier //save event id to access this particular event later
        } catch {
            // Display error to user
        }
    }
}
```